# How to "include" common methods in groovys

Tags: groovy

I have developed a number of groovys used as plugins by Serviio.
Many of the methods used by these plugins are common, but when changes are made, each plugin needs to be updated. Therefore I want to "include" those methods in each plugin from a tools.groovy. I have tried 2 different approaches suggested in other posts.

I tried using

```
evaluate(new File("C:\\Program Files\\Serviio\\plugins\\tools.groovy"))
```

at the start of each plugin where tools.groovy just has

```
class Tools{method1{return}method2{return}}
```

but when executing the plugin I get

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Tools.main() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

If I then add

```
void main(args) { }
```

to class Tools, the error goes away but that Tools.main is run instead of the plugin.main and I get no output.

My second approach as suggested was to use

```
def script = new GroovyScriptEngine( '.' ).with {
  loadScriptByName( 'C:\\Program Files\\Serviio\\plugins\\tools.groovy' )
} 
this.metaClass.mixin script
```

This however gives the error

```
unexpected token: this @ line 55, column 2.
this.metaClass.mixin script
```

Any suggestions on how to make either of these solutions work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try defining a common base script and giving it as a compiler configuration.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy

From the groovy documentation...

```
class ScriptBaseTest {

  @Test
  void extend_groovy_script() {
    def compiler = new CompilerConfiguration()
    compiler.setScriptBaseClass("ScriptBaseTestScript")

    def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new Binding(), compiler)

    assertEquals shell.evaluate("foo()"), "this is foo"
  }
}

abstract class ScriptBaseTestScript extends Script {
  def foo() {
    "this is foo"
  }
}
```